# Creating specificity in Material UI Next and React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a class specificity in Material UI Next same way as they allow you to use pseudo classes, but for nested elements. For example, in Material UI Next (MUI-Next) I can create a class with styles in it:

```
const styles = {
  appbar: {
     background: '#6d6146',
     '&:hover': {
        background: '#9e8e6a',
     },
  },
};
```

and use it this way

```
<Toolbar className={classes.appbar}>
  ... blah blah blah
</Toolbar>
```

That paints my Toolbar element in color `#6d6146` and hovers to `#9e8e6a`.

Now, if imagine I have some elements inside the Toolbar and I don't want to create a class for every single element in it. (especially if they are not MUI-Next elements, but some custom HTML) For the sake of an example, a hyperlink. Like this:

```
<Toolbar className={classes.appbar}>
   <a href="www.google.com">
      <span>Title</span>
   </a>
</Toolbar>
```

Yes, there are ways to do this particular example correctly using MUI control properties, remember this is an example. Real world code is very complex and lots of code.

I would like to access that hyperlink by way of specificity using the main parent class as a hook class. The desired rendered css would look like this:

```
.appbar {
    background: #6d6146;
}
.appbar:hover {
    background: #9e8e6a;
}
.appbar a{
    color: #d63302;
}
```

My attempt to create specificity is not working. This is what I tried:

```
const styles = {
   appbar: {
      background: '#6d6146',
      '&:hover': {
          background: '#9e8e6a',
      },
      'a': {
        color: '#d63302',
      },
   },
};
```

According to how MUI-Next handles pseudo-classes to create specificity, this element specificity should work, but doesn't. Can this be done and I am not using the right syntax, or is this not supported?

Remember this is Material UI Next found [here](https://material-ui-next.com/). Completely different than the older Material UI.

Here is a playground for ya. Thanks in advance.

[**SAMPLE CODE**](https://codesandbox.io/s/y330pq9rn1)

Comment: "My attempt to create specificity is not working." – what do you mean by this?

Comment: Is not creating the specificity. No CSS is being rendered

Comment: What is the desired behavior?

Comment: It's in the question

Comment: Have you tried: `<a href="www.google.com" className={classes.appbar.a}>`?

Comment: Seriously man, you have to read the question fully - "I don't want to create a class for every single element in it". This is a simple example to show the behavior. The real world has thousands of lines of code that are all dependent of APIs I can't reproduce here. Don't look at the example literally.

Comment: And no, `className={classes.appbar.a}` is not proper syntax

Comment: Alright I'll sit this one out. It is proper syntax though.

Comment: Did you try it in my code sandbox? I did and nothing happened

Comment: I did, forked sandbox is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/j7v1zoy8o9

Comment: I don't see the hyperlink in red. If it worked, it should have turned it red. But it doesn't matter, I can't attach a class for hundreds of elements in the HTML structure I have anyway. Thank you tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
appbar: {
    background: "#6d6146",
    "&:hover": {
      background: "#9e8e6a"
    },
    "& a": {
      color: "black",
      "&:hover": {
        color: "red"
      }
    }
  }
```

Working [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/p2k83oljy0)

Comment: That's the sauce! Thank you!